# Limit the element within the array to appear X times

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

***Functionality:***

A display container will display a randomised element from an array. Each element within the array can only be displayed x no. of times.

***Issue:***

I am not sure on how to limit each individual element within the array to be displayed x no. of times.

I have randomised all elements within  the array, hence at this point in time, the elements in the array will be displayed whenever it is randomised and not limited.

Each of my element within an array is a file name.

Therefore, how am I able to limit the number of times each element in the array is displayed

For example:

lib/image/Voucher/Andn.png => can only be displayed 3 times

lib/image/Voucher/Brelk.png => can only be displayed once

lib/image/Voucher/Cele.png => can only be displayed 6 times

lib/image/Voucher/Chrm.png => can only be displayed 13 times

***Code:***

```js
var DisplayOfferArray = ["lib/image/Voucher/Andn.png", "lib/image/Voucher/Brelk.png", "lib/image/Voucher/Cele.png", "lib/image/Voucher/Chrm.png"];


var printOfferFrame = "";
var Offer_list = [];
var random_Offer;


//randomise Offer Array
random_Offer = Math.floor(Math.random() * DisplayOfferArray.length);
Offer_list.push(random_Offer);


//Display randomised Offer from offer array
$("#Offer_Description").attr('src', DisplayOfferArray[random_Offer]).show();
```

```html
<img id="Offer_Description" style="position:absolute; width: 950px; height:565px; top:640px; left:70px; z-index=99; margin:auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

keep track of every usage!
change your array to this:

```
var DisplayOfferArray = [{"src" : "lib/image/Voucher/Andn.png", "usage" : **N**}, ...];
```

and then change your random index generator to this:

```
random_Offer = Math.floor(Math.random() * DisplayOfferArray.length);
while (DisplayOfferArray[random_Offer].usage == 0) random_Offer = Math.floor(Math.random() * DisplayOfferArray.length);
DisplayOfferArray[random_Offer].usage --;
```

Comment: so, after which i can still perform this line of code as per normal: `Offer_list.push(random_Offer);`, correct??

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. I would assume that when the usage is 0, it shouldnt be randomising anymore, but remove. so as to prevent the array from randomising the element again

Comment: for your first question the answer is yes!
and regarding for your second question, it doesn't matter, unless you have too much element in that array! if your array is small then removing it from the array takes more time than re-randomizing!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a map to keep track of times a value has been used:

```js
var DisplayOfferArray = [{
    value: "lib/image/Voucher/Andn.png",
    current: 0,
    max: 2,
  }, {
    value: "lib/image/Voucher/Brelk.png",
    current: 0,
    max: 3,
  }, {
    value: "lib/image/Voucher/Cele.png",
    current: 0,
    max: 4,
  }, {
    value: "lib/image/Voucher/Chrm.png",
    current: 0,
    max: 5,
  },
];

function getOffer() {
  var random_Offer = Math.floor(Math.random() * DisplayOfferArray.length);

  var offer = DisplayOfferArray[random_Offer];

  if (offer.current >= offer.max) {
    // remove the offer from array to prevent infinite loop
    DisplayOfferArray.splice(random_Offer, 1);
    return getOffer();
  }

  offer.current++;
  return offer.value;
};

//Display randomised Offer from offer array
$("#Offer_Description").attr('src', getOffer()).show();
```

```html
<img id="Offer_Description" style="position:absolute; width: 950px; height:565px; top:640px; left:70px; z-index=99; margin:auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:
Counting array index with another array.And match with each `index` of calc array.It will store the increment value.Then match with condition .And separate with switch case.

```js
var calc =['1','1','1','1'];
var some = setInterval(function (){
var DisplayOfferArray = ["lib/image/Voucher/Andn.png", "lib/image/Voucher/Brelk.png", "lib/image/Voucher/Cele.png", "lib/image/Voucher/Chrm.png"];


var printOfferFrame = "";
var Offer_list = [];
var random_Offer;


//randomise Offer Array
random_Offer = Math.floor(Math.random() * DisplayOfferArray.length);
Offer_list.push(random_Offer);

 switch(random_Offer){
  case 0:
      if(calc[random_Offer] < 3){calc[random_Offer] ++;
                 $("#Offer_Description").attr('src', DisplayOfferArray[random_Offer])}
  break;
      case 1:
      if(calc[random_Offer] < 1){calc[random_Offer] ++;
     $("#Offer_Description").attr('src', DisplayOfferArray[random_Offer])}
  break;
      case 2:
      if(calc[random_Offer] < 6){calc[random_Offer] ++;
       $("#Offer_Description").attr('src', DisplayOfferArray[random_Offer])}
  break;
      case 3:
      if(calc[random_Offer] < 13){calc[random_Offer] ++;
       $("#Offer_Description").attr('src', DisplayOfferArray[random_Offer])}
  break;
    }
      
    document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML=calc.join(":");
  },100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="Offer_Description" style="position:absolute; width: 950px; height:565px; top:640px; left:70px; z-index=99; margin:auto;">
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track how many times a value is used, but you can also choose to fill a secondary array with all values the number of times they can occur and display a random value from that array, removing the used item in the process.

```js
//Not strictly necessary, but for easy of maintenance keep the count inside the same object 
let DisplayOfferArray = [{img:"lib/image/Voucher/Andn.png",cnt:3},{img: "lib/image/Voucher/Brelk.png",cnt:1}, {img:"lib/image/Voucher/Cele.png",cnt:6}, {img:"lib/image/Voucher/Chrm.png",cnt:13}];

//fill Offer_List with all items
let Offer_list = DisplayOfferArray.reduce((arr,o)=>{for(let i=0; i<o.cnt; i++)arr.push(o); return arr;}, []);

function getNextOffer(){
 let index =  Math.floor(Math.random() * Offer_list.length); //random index in the remaining items
  return Offer_list.splice(index,1)[0].img; 
}

while(Offer_list.length) //emulate loop. this is probably done in realtime with some timeout function
 console.log(getNextOffer()); //for test, display the result (you can set the image with the results of getNextOffer())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```